# Pesukei de-Zimra in Sidur of Amram Gaon

Tags: prayer-book, shacharis-morning-prayer, pesukei-dezimra

What Psalms were included in the Pesukei de-Zimra in the Siddur of Amram Gaon on weekdays, as well as on Shabbat and Holidays?

Answer (score 2):

R. Amram writes that in the Babylonian yeshiva they would say אלה ברכב ואלה בסוסים... המה כרעו ונפלו... ה' הושיעה המלך יעננו... ברוך אתה ה' אמ"ה הא-ל המלך המהולל בפי עמו...
Then they would say יהי כבוד, as in our siddurim, followed by Ashrei, the Hallelukahs, Vayevarech David until ומהללים לשם תפארתך, and then ישתבח.

On Shabbos, there are different versions about what was said. One version has הודו followed by the 7 mizmorim we say. Another has מזמור לתודה and הודו. All conclude with נשמת.

Comment: what are the 7 Psalms on Shabbat and Yoim Toiv? There are 9 of them in the Ashkenazi rite, and 14 in the Sephardic rite.